# How to install C++Builder (RAD Studio) documentation

Tags: installation, ide, c++builder, rad-studio

I've clicked a "Help" button in an error message box shown by the C++Builder IDE, and another error message box pops up telling me

> RAD Studio's help is not installed. Please reinstall RAD Studio's documentation.

So I seem to have missed checking the checkbox for installing the help when installing C++Builder 11.2. I would like to fix that and install the documentation.

When I invoke the C++Builder installer again, the installer says

> A previous version of RAD Studio 11 was found on your system that needs to be uninstalled first.

But the message is not quite correct, it is not a previous version that is installed, but the exact same version: 11.2 is currently installed, and the installer that I execute is for 11.2, and exactly the same installer that I have previously used to install the current version. I've double-checked.

Is uninstalling and reinstalling the only way to get the documentation for the 11.2 version, or is there some way how I can just add the documentation to the existing installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

As Remy Lebeau has pointed out in a comment to this answer, you can open a "feature manager" inside RADStudio by choosing menu item Tools->"Manage Platforms..." which will show you all options from the installer again, and allow to change the options and apply the changes.

I wish I had known this before I actually uninstalled and reinstalled C++Builder with some hassles (described in the original answer).

Comment: You should not have had to do a full uninstall and reinstall just to add the Help. You probably could have just gone into the [Feature Manager](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Feature_Manager) to add it after the IDE was already installed. See [Adding or Removing Features Using the Feature Manager](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_or_Removing_Features_Using_the_Feature_Manager) in the online documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wow thanks, that would have saved me some time! I'll edit my answer to include your hint.